# How to move accented files using `Batch`?

Tags: batch-file

If I move an accented file to the same directory using the command prompt, it works correctly.

```
move ó.mp3 ó.mp3
```

However, when I use the same command in a `.bat` file, the following error appears: `the system cannot find the file specified`.

```
@echo off
move ó.mp3 ó.mp3
pause
```

Comment: does this work? `forfiles /P "%__APPDIR__%." /M "cmd.exe" /C "cmd /c move 0xA2.mp3 0xA2.mp3"`

Comment: Are you in the selected folder in your batch file? Try using the full path of the files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A flagrant [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case. I guess that you save the script using Windows' native `notepad` editor using co-called *ANSI* encoding. The following *commented* code snippet could enlighten the problem:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions

REM save current code page (optional)
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%G in ('CHCP') do set "_currentCP=%%H"
REM find notepad's ("ANSI") code page
for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%G in ('
  REG QUERY "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage" -v ACP^|find "ACP"
') do set "_notepadCP=%%I"

REM show flagrant mojibake case
echo %_currentCP%: move ó.mp3 óó.mp3

REM change the active console code page and show right result  
>NUL CHCP %_notepadCP%
echo %_notepadCP%: move ó.mp3 óó.mp3

REM reurn the active console code page to saved value (optional)
>NUL CHCP %_currentCP%

pause
```

**Result**:

```
D:\bat\SO\61743331.bat
```

> ```
>  852: move ˇ.mp3 ˇˇ.mp3
> 1250: move ó.mp3 óó.mp3
> ```

I see above output on my (Central European) Windows. On Western Windows, you could see something like

> ```
>  850: move ¾.mp3 ¾¾.mp3
> 1252: move ó.mp3 óó.mp3
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You should change the code page with this command [CHCP /?](https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html)

```bat
@echo off
CHCP 65001>nul
move ó.mp3 ó.mp3
pause
```